# NSURL taking a long time to return URL's contents. Is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am using NSURL to submit MySQL queries to a web server to store my app's data. Problem is, the request takes around 15 seconds even for a simple 5 word reply. I have made my code as streamlined as possible, but I do not think it has sped up at all.
Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.casacorazon.org/ios.html")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

If you know of a way to make the code run a bit faster, or trim the 15 seconds down I would love to know.
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Have you narrowed down the issue to the posted code or the server's response time?

Comment: Figure out how to make the same call using 'curl' from Terminal, and see how long it takes on the Mac. If same, its the network or server, if much faster something is wrong in your app.

Answer (score 3):

You are networking. You are not in change of the network. That's just how life is. You should not care how long it takes. Your callback method will be called back asynchronously, whenever the network communication finishes. It could be ten minutes from now (well, maybe not, because there would probably be a timeout before that). It is your job to code in such a way that that indeterminate lapse of time is okay.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to run the callback in a prioritized queue. Try this and it would be great if you comment whether or not it made a difference, if not I'll delete the answer and save myself from more embarrassment :)

```
@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.casacorazon.org/ios.html")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            if error != nil {
                 print("Error: \(error)")
            } 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.testLabel.text = "\(responseString!)"
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Lightning. Fast. You are a god to me

Comment: It's nearly instantaneous

Comment: lol, you can up vote it by clicking the up arrow above 0.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers